# set constant width to every bar in a bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, seaborn

I am trying to plot a bar plot where each bin has a difference length and as a result I end up with a very ugly result.c:) What I would like to do is still be able to define a bin of deference lengths but all the bars be plotted the same fixed width. How can I do that? Here is what I have done so far:

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_palette("deep", desat=.6)
sns.set_context(rc={"figure.figsize": (8, 4)})
np.random.seed(9221999)

data = [0,2,30,40,50,10,50,40,150,70,150,10,3,70,70,90,10,2] 
bins = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200]
plt.hist(data, bins=bins);
```

[image]

**EDIT**

This question has been marked as duplicate but in fact non of the proposed links solved my problem; the 1st is a very crappy workaround and the 2nd doesn't solve the problem at all as it sets all bars' width to a certain number.

Comment: @Andy sorry but non of your links solves my problem. see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, with `seaborn`, as you please. But you have to understand that `seaborn` itself *uses* `matplotlib` to create plots.
AND: Please delete your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541878/), now it really is a duplicate.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_palette("deep", desat=.6)
sns.set_context(rc={"figure.figsize": (8, 4)})

data = [0,2,30,40,50,10,50,40,150,70,150,10,3,70,70,90,10,2]
bins = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200]


bin_middles = bins[:-1] + np.diff(bins)/2.
bar_width = 1. 
m, bins = np.histogram(data, bins)
plt.bar(np.arange(len(m)) + (1-bar_width)/2., m, width=bar_width)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(bins)))
ax.set_xticklabels(['{:.0f}'.format(i) for i in bins])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Personally I think, that plotting your data like this is confusing. Having non-linear (or non-log) axis scaling is usually not a good idea.

Comment: ok so I deleted my other question. Also, thanks for your answer, but why are there so many spaces between?

Comment: Well, have a look at `data`. For example, there are just no values between `5` and `6`. Wikipedia has a good article on [historgrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) and how they are built

Answer (score 2):

Are you wanting to place a bar with a fixed width at the center of each bin?

If so, try something something similar to this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [0,2,30,40,50,10,50,40,150,70,150,10,3,70,70,90,10,2]
bins = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200]

counts, _ = np.histogram(data, bins)
centers = np.mean([bins[:-1], bins[1:]], axis=0)

plt.bar(centers, counts, width=5, align='center')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This might work but as you can see I am working with different libraries. Any ideas?

Comment: @user706838 - You're not working with different libraries at all... You're using matplotlib and numpy.  `seaborn` is just a thin wrapper around matplotlib.  Your plot will look slightly different due to the different default styles, but the code in my example won't change.

Comment: I can't see the similarity though... I would appreciate if you could apply your idea on the plt.hist() function. Can you please do that for me?

Comment: You cannot do this with hist. All `hist` does is to use `np.histogram ` and then call `plt.bar ` in a specific way.